# Content scripts not trapping chrome.tabs.onUpdate

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am developing a Google Chrome Extension. I want to get the contents(text only) of the active tab. I am sure that Content scripts will help me find what I am looking for.

But I am stuck in the below scenario:

If I run my chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(){ in my background.js, I am able to achieve other tasks, say ajax post etc. But if I include document.body.innerHTML in that chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(){, to get the contents of the opened tab, it is alerting the contents of my background.html and NOT the contents of the tab which is opened in the browser.

If I paste the chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(){ in my content scripts, I am not able to trap the tab update.

Can I know where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Try like this:

```
// In background.js
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
  if (changeInfo.status === 'complete') {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, {type: 'getDoc'}, function (doc) {
      console.log(doc);
    });
  }
});

// In content_scripts.js
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, response) {
  if (request.type === 'getDoc') {
    response(document.body.innerHTML);
  }

  return true;
});
```

Comment: Using your code, I'm getting "runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.". How can I fixed that?